# Number of one-to-one functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \to \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ such that $f(1) \neq 0, 1$ and $f(i) \neq i$ for $i = 2, 3, 4, 5$

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

This was a question from a test. There's a set $A$ with elements $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and another set $B$ with elements $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. Now $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(1)$ is not equal to $0$ or $1$ and $f(i)$ is not equal to $i$ (for $i=2,3,4,5$). Then how many such one to one functions are possible?

It looks like an application of the derangement formula, but it's getting way too complex when I apply it. Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: The same problem was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666475/a-1-2-3-4-5-b-0-1-2-3-4-5-find-the-number-of-one-one-functions-f) and solved in a different way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce 0 in set A and place it in position which is not occupied by any 5 elements in set A(no of cases still remain same).

If 0 takes 0 , then it is simply $d_5$

If 0 does not take 0 it would have been $d_6$ if 1 could take 0 but u see 1 has equal probability going to 0,2,3,4,5 right. Out of $d_6$ every 4 out of 5 cases should be counted

Answer is simply $d_5$ + $\frac{4d_6}{5}$ = 44 + $\frac{4*265}{5}$ = 44 + 212=256

Comment: Can u kindly explain how can we introduce 0 in set A and still have the total no. of cases unaltered?

Comment: Oo i got it...thanks a lot! Such an interesting approach to a mind-boggling problem(atleast for me)!

Answer (score 3):

Well the problem may be solved by a simple algorithm which always works in every problem of derrangement and is derived from its proof.
Set $f(1)=2$
Now you have to assign values to $x=3,4,5$ under constraint of $f(i)$ not equal to $i, 2$ is free to go anywhere as we already assigned $2$ of codomain to $f(1)$.
By inclusion exclusion,
Total unconditional ways $= \binom54 \times 4!$
Now subtract cases in which one of $3,4,5$ was matched to $3,4,5$ of codomain .
But now you subtracted the number of cases in which $2$ of $3,4,5$ was matched to $2$ of $3,4,5$ in codomain twice  ,so add it.
And so on ....
Total cases are $$\binom54\times 4!-\binom31\times \binom43\times 3!+\binom32\times \binom32\times 2!-\binom33\times \binom21\times 1!=64$$
Since $f(1)$ may take $2,3,4,5$ and all those cases are symmetrical .
Total ways$=4\times64=256$